# Using a placeholder for a subset condition in an ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make an ActiveRecord query that generates the below SQL:

```
SELECT "tickets".* FROM "tickets"  WHERE (status IN ('Complete','Cancelled'))
```

The catch is that I'm trying to do it with a placeholder, i.e., I can't just do

```
Ticket.where(status: ['Complete','Cancelled'])
```

It has to be something like this:

```
Ticket.where(['status IN (?)', "'Complete','Cancelled'"])
```

However I cannot figure out how to escape the outer quotes in the second argument. The generated SQL ends up as `status IN ('''Complete'',''Cancelled''')`

Is there a way to accomplish this? The reason for this is that I am chaining queries together, but as "OR" conditions, and Rails has no straightforward way to dynamically perform unions that I know of. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please explain last paragraph more detail (with examples)? Seems like your example above and your real problem is different.

Comment: Eventually I will end up with a long query, e.g., `('status IN (?) OR created_at > (?)', arg1, arg2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a string `"'Complete','Cancelled'"` you should split it by `,` symbol, remove `'` and pass array to `where` cause:

```
Ticket.where('status IN (?)', ['Complete', 'Cancelled'])
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Could have sworn I tried that... silly me